# calling VBA function in Access from Java

Tags: java, ms-access, vba, jdbc-odbc

I have a database designed using MS Access with a VBA function written in the database
When I try to call this function from a java program using JdbcOdbc Bridge I get SQLException with the message meaning "function is not found" 
the function access modifier in the DB is "public" and I tried to use "ExtendedAnsiSQL=1" in the connection URL but I failed 
Is there something missing or these functions cannot be called from external programs ?

Comment: The question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677632/ms-access-from-java-undefined-function-in-expression

There is no way to have user defined functions in a SQL query if you don't run it in the MS Access environment.

Answer (score 1):

MS Access comes in two parts, the Jet/ACE database, which you are connecting to, and the "front-end", for want of a better word, that holds the forms, reports and code. I do not believe you will be able to reference code in MS Access without an instance of the application.

Comment: I don't seem to read your response correctly :
which application I must have an instance of ?